# Stop connecting to a particular wifi network based on my location

Tags: wi-fi, tasker

I'm trying to get my head aroud how to use Tasker to solve a problem I face.

In short, I am exposed to two wifi networks that have the same SSID, 'NETGEAR' . One is in use at my parents, and my phone is setup to connect to this network with the relevant encryption key.

The other is in use near my office, I dont have access to that network ( and dont want it)

The problem is that my phone will try to connect to the NETGEAR network at my office, thinking it is the same network that it already knows about. I'd like my phone to ignore that network while not at my parents house.

Is this something Tasker can accomplish, or is there a better approach? I do not want to delete and re-setup the network all the time.

Comment: Easiest way would be to change the SSID at your parents, then go into wifi settings and forget the work SSID. Strange you should be able to connect to both considering different passwords in each network

Comment: That's just it, it doesn't connect at work, but sits there trying and trying until it eventually gives up and tries one of the correct office networks ( or I notice and force it to change)

Comment: Are the SSID for home and work separate listing? If so just tell phone to forget the work one. There is a way to set connection according to geographic location, which will run GPS all time., but I havent tried.

Comment: I've set my phone up to attempt to connect to the SSID 'NETGEAR' So I can use my parents wifi. It also tried to connect to another network that happens to have the same SSID. This is what I want to stop.

Comment: Either set it up to GPS location or change the SSID at parents. The second being the easiest.  Just go to home page for the router, enter the passphrase, change SSID, then save/apply setting.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to add a location context to the profile.
Alternatively, if you are at work or your parents house at consistent times, you could add a time context to the profile.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Option 1: Long press the trigger in the profile you are using and tap add, then choose State > Location and enter the location where you would want it to trigger.

Option 2: Long press the trigger in the profile you are using and tap add, then choose Time, then choose the time you would like your task to trigger.